CropBox filter to PointCloud2
I'm trying to apply a CropBox filter to point cloud from a sensor that includes additional fields.
It works fine using PointXYZ.
This is my callback to the sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2
From .hpp:
Eigen::Vector4f minPt_;
Eigen::Vector4f maxPt_;
pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter_;

From .cpp:
void LidarMaskPointCloudFilter::rawPointCloudCallback(
    const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr inputPcdMsg
)
{
    // create a pcl type point cloud from ros msg
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr
        inputCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*inputPcdMsg, *inputCloud);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr
        filteredCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    boxFilter_.setMin(minPt);
    boxFilter_.setMax(maxPt);
    boxFilter_.setTransform(lidarToBox);
    boxFilter_.setNegative(true);
    boxFilter_.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
    boxFilter_.filter(*filteredCloud);
    // prepare msg and publish
    sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 filteredPcdMsg;
    pcl::toROSMsg(*filteredCloud, filteredPcdMsg);
    filteredPcdMsg.header = inputPcdMsg->header;
    filteredPointCloudPub_->publish(filteredPcdMsg);
}

Since PointXYZ only retains the XYZ fields, I want to use PCLPointCloud2 to keep the other fields. I thought it was going to be as simple as replacing pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter_; with pcl::CropBox<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> boxFilter_; but it doesn't work.
The code is pretty much identical to the above.
From .hpp:
Eigen::Vector4f minPt_;
Eigen::Vector4f maxPt_;
pcl::CropBox<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> boxFilter_;

From .cpp:
void LidarMaskPointCloudFilter::rawPointCloudCallback(
    const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr inputPcdMsg
)
{
    // create a pcl type point cloud from ros msg
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::Ptr
        inputCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>);
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*inputPcdMsg, *inputCloud);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::Ptr
        filteredCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>);
    boxFilter_.setMin(minPt);
    boxFilter_.setMax(maxPt);
    boxFilter_.setTransform(lidarToBox);
    boxFilter_.setNegative(true);
    boxFilter_.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
    boxFilter_.filter(*filteredCloud);
    // prepare msg and publish
    sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 filteredPcdMsg;
    pcl::toROSMsg(*filteredCloud, filteredPcdMsg);
    filteredPcdMsg.header = inputPcdMsg->header;
    filteredPointCloudPub_->publish(filteredPcdMsg);
}

This is the main error:
error: cannot convert ‘const Ptr’ {aka ‘const std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> >’} to ‘const PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr&’ {aka ‘const std::shared_ptr<const pcl::PCLPointCloud2>&’}
  160 |     boxFilter_.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const Ptr {aka const std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> >}

EDIT:
Added @BTables' suggestion.
These are the errors I still have:
error: no matching function for call to ‘fromROSMsg(std::__shared_ptr_access<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type&, std::__shared_ptr_access<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type&)’
  126 |     pcl::fromROSMsg(*inputPcdMsg, *inputCloud);


error: cannot convert ‘shared_ptr<PointCloud<[...]>>’ to ‘shared_ptr<PointCloud<[...]>>’
  131 |         inputCloud,
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         shared_ptr<PointCloud<[...]>>


error: cannot convert ‘const Ptr’ {aka ‘const std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> >’} to ‘const PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr&’ {aka ‘const std::shared_ptr<const pcl::PCLPointCloud2>&’}
  160 |     boxFilter_.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const Ptr {aka const std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> >}


error: no matching function for call to ‘pcl::CropBox<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::filter(std::__shared_ptr_access<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type&)’
  161 |     boxFilter_.filter(*filteredCloud);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct pcl::traits::fieldList<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>’
  195 | struct fieldList /** \cond NO_WARN_RECURSIVE */ : fieldList<typename POD<PointT>::type> /** \endcond */
      |        ^~~~~~~~~


error: could not convert ‘pcl::traits::fieldList<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::POINT_TYPE_NOT_PROPERLY_REGISTERED201::assert_arg()’ from ‘mpl_::failed************ (pcl::traits::fieldList<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::POINT_TYPE_NOT_PROPERLY_REGISTERED::************)(pcl::PCLPointCloud2&)’ to ‘mpl_::assert<false>::type’ {aka ‘mpl_::assert<false>’}
  201 |   BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG((!std::is_same<PointT, typename POD<PointT>::type>::value),
      |   ^
      |   |
      |   mpl_::failed************ (pcl::traits::fieldList<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::POINT_TYPE_NOT_PROPERLY_REGISTERED::************)(pcl::PCLPointCloud2&)


error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct pcl::traits::fieldList<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>’
  263 |     for_each_type<typename traits::fieldList<PointT>::type> (detail::FieldAdder<PointT>(msg.fields));
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


The issue is that you're declaring a pointcloud of type, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::Ptr. However, from the error your function is expecting pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::ConstPtr(which is a typdef of const std::shared_ptr<const pcl::PCLPointCloud2>&.
You can fix this by changing your definition to the appropriate const ptr:
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::ConstPtr
        inputCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>);


good catch. Please see my edit
